# Older system, latest version of flash player doesn't work

Tags: 12.04, flash

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.3 on a 32bit system with 2.0GB of RAM, AMD Athlon XP 2000+ CPU and a GeForce 2600 video card.  I can't get the current version of Flash Player to work.  I know there is a fix for older systems, but can't figure it out.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, installing an older flash fixed it.

Download and install [Adobe Flash player plugin v10.3.x.x](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html#flash_player_archives), download the latest version on the 10.3.x.x series. At the time I installed, it was v10.3.183.43, and I will use that one for the examples.

The file is huge (61 MB), and contains a lot of stuff, but we will extract it, and then extract another .tar.gz file that is the one that contains the libflashplayer.so file we are going to install.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
unzip fp_10.3.183.43_archive.zip && cd fp_10.3.r183.43_archive/10_3_r183_43/
tar -xvzf flashplayer_10_3r183_43_linux.tar.gz && cd flashplayer_10_3r183_43_linux
sudo mkdir -p /opt/flashplugin-nonfree/v10.3.183.43
sudo cp libflashplayer.so /opt/flashplugin-nonfree/v10.3.183.43/
```

Now that you have the file for Flash player v10.3.183.43 in place, we use update-alternatives to install it as an alternative of a Flash player

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/flash-mozilla.so  flash-mozilla.so /opt/flashplugin-nonfree/v10.3.183.43/libflashplayer.so 10
```

Then, just in case you have another version of Flash installed (for example, the broken one that gets installed with the flashplugin-nonfree package), run this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config flash-mozilla.so
```

This will prompt you to select a choice for the alternative flash-mozilla.so.
Just select the one we just installed. Don't worry at all about the auto/manual stuff regarding alternatives, just ignore that.

Comment: Appreciate the help, but I found a fantastic and easy answer at http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linuxquestions-org-member-success-stories-23/getting-flash-plug-in-to-work-with-older-cpus-4175420481/.  I used version 10.183.90 debug and I'm up and running.